# Running jQuery function when div "is" and "is not" in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 4 divs set to a height of 100% so that each div takes up the view of the whole screen.

When I scroll down to a div with say ID #port and most of it is in view I want it to run a jQuery function and when it is not in view anymore i want it to run another function.

I can get it to work when you scroll down to the div. when the div is almost to the top it runs my functions but once that same "portfolio" div is no longer in view i need it to run another function.

here is what I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var port = $('#port').offset().top - 10;

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = $('body').scrollTop();
    if( top > port ){
      function1();
      function2();
    }else{
      function3();
     }
   });
 });
```

Again I can get it to run the function1 and function2 once the div is almost to the top but I need it the run a third function when the same div is no longer in view.

ALSO - If there is a better way to go about this please let me know. I am familiar with jQuery but still consider myself a noob compared to others.

Comment: This might be exactly what you need. http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Kewl, that worked for me.